# When creating my own View in Android, the bottom area where the context menu inflates is Black. How can I fix this?

Tags: android-layout

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <test.viewz.MazeView
        android:id="@+id/mazeView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</FrameLayout>
```

So this is supposed to create a 3x4 grid and I have the sizing work out fine (to the best of my knowledge) but no matter what I have tried changing, I can't seem to get the Canvas to paint in the bottom section of the screen. Any help? And any more information I need to provide?

Comment: Your layout seems fine, we'll have to see the code from the custom view.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It turns out the problem was in the way I had my raster set up. I accidentally made it column major and it was paint some of the pixels off screen and not reaching far enough with the height. It just so happened that the difference in the width and the height of my screen is about the same as an options menu. Thanks for everybody's time.